# Flex preloader not showing up

Tags: apache-flex, flash, preloader

For some weird reason the preloader for my Flex 3.5 application does not show up. The application SWF is around 550KB. Am not using RSLs. From the Activity tab in Safari I see the progress of the SWF loading in the browser. After the SWF is loaded. The preloader comes for a split second, moves from 0 to 100 and goes away.

Any solution or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show some code and/or an example.

Comment: Make sure than you don't use Flex SDK classes like `mx:VBox` or `mx:Image` in your preloader. Try to write in pure AS 3.0.

Comment: I am using the default Flex preloader. Using swfobject for embedding the Flash movie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swfdump from the Flex 4 SDK (just call it from the command line) to see the structure of the SWF.  Make sure there are many (35-ish) DoABC2 tags before the second FrameLabel tag.  If that is the case then your problem is that you are initializing too much stuff on startup (after the preloader is gone).  Use deferred instantiation to prevent so many things from being created at startup.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Am trying it out.

Comment: Any luch with this?  I'm suffering from the same issue.  I've tried deferring 75% of the app at this point.  It was working great until Flash 11.5.